# Where do I put my setenv.sh? (Tomcat8 installled via yum)

Tags: java, tomcat8

Where do I put my setenv.sh? I installed Tomcat8 via yum on CentOS.

Comment: On a previous Ubuntu installation of tomcat8, the /bin directory contains loads of other .sh files including Catalina.sh but cant find any of them on the CentOS yum install

Answer (score 4):

setenv.sh is not used under RHEL/CentOS yum installation because the /usr/sbin/tomcat8 does not recognise catalina.s. Instead, it calls the tomcat bootstrap class directly.

The best place is to put the values in /etc/tomcat8/tomcat8.conf

Alternatively, use the Tomcat8 tar.gz.

Comment: on debian add options in this file:

/etc/default/tomcat8